# Izpack installer for non-java applications

Tags: installation, izpack

Can the Izpack installer be used to install a non-java application?

Thanks,
Abdulfattah.

Answer (score 0):

It should be. It will bundle everything together in a jar file. For the pack tag of the install file, call the following:

```
<pack name="PROJECTPACKNAME" required="yes" preselected="yes"
        installGroups="New Application">
        <description>PROJECT install</description>
        <file src="@{DIRECTORYNAME.dir}" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
    </pack>
```

For DIRECTORYNAME, you have to declare a property in your build file, ie:

```
<property name="DIRECTORYNAME.dir" value="/apps/MyProjectName"/>
```

then have a target in the build file:

```
<target name="SftWreBundle" depends="init" description="build the software bundle">

    <taskdef name="izpack" classpath="${izpack.dir}/lib/standalone-compiler.jar" classname="com.izforge.izpack.ant.IzPackTask" />
    <izpack input="install.xml" output="${dist}/${product.short.name}-${product.version}-install.jar" 
        installerType="standard" inheritAll="true" 
        basedir="${basedir}" compression="deflate" compressionlevel="9" />
</target>
```

You may want to clean your working directory before running this target.